# Eclipse IDE - Increase size of dotted outline on dialogue checkboxes

Tags: eclipse, checkbox, ide, outline

Please see the example picture below, the dotted line around the checkbox question. How do I increase its size in Eclipse IDE? My current size is too small and makes the text unreadable.

[image]

I use the theme: Darkest Dark

Comment: This looks like a problem with High DPI monitor. Please raise a bug at bugs.eclipse.org against SWT with Display resolution and Scaling factor used.

Comment: Yes, it could be. I have a 2560x1440 144Hz Monitor

Comment: No it's not, I moved the window to my 1080 Monitor and it appears the same.

Comment: You can get the scaling factor from Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display.

Comment: the scaling factor is a available at Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display. here you can select in 100%,150% etc

Comment: There is no work around for this problem please raise a bug for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fix for this problem, I am submitting this to Eclipse bugs.

I will update this answer once there is a resolution or the bug is fixed.

BUG DETAILS
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512850

ID:512850

Comment: Add the bug number here.